# RSpec error for destroy action - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to write an rspec test for my destroy action of my `user_stocks_controller` but I get an error:

> UserStocksController DELETE #destroy deletes stock Failure/Error:
>   delete :destroy, params: { id: user_stock.id }
>
> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches
>   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"user_stocks", :id=>nil}

I have read that the problem exist because I didn't give id for stock. I was trying to change it on a multi different way but of my ideas wasn't right.

Here is my spec:

```
let(:user) { User.new(email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password') }

  before do
    sign_in(user)
  end

 describe 'DELETE #destroy' do
    let(:stock) { Stock.new_from_lookup('GS') }
    let(:user_stock) { UserStock.create(user: user.id, stock: stock) }

    it 'deletes stock' do
      expect do
        delete :destroy, params: { id: user_stock.id }
      end.to change(UserStock, :count).by(-1)
      expect(response).to have_http_status(redirect)
      expect(flash[:notice]).to eq 'Stock successfully removed'
    end
  end
```

Destroy method in user_stocks_controller:

```
  def destroy
    stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
    @user_stock = UserStock.where(user_id: current_user.id, stock_id: stock.id).first
    @user_stock.destroy!
    flash[:notice] = 'Stock successfully removed'
    redirect_to my_portfolio_path
  end
```

Why is not detecting my routes even when I set `id` for it?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of rails are you using? There are examples in [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/templates/controller_spec.rb#L169-L179) github repo on how to do destroy depending on rails version < 5 or rails >5 the syntax is different.

If you rails version is < 5 then try

`delete :destroy, {id: user_stock.id}`

Another solution would be try to use the delete path so based on your routes something like below

`delete "/user_stocks/#{user_stock.id}"`

Comment: I'm using rails 5.2.2. In your first solution I've got an error -  ```ArgumentError: unknown keyword: id``` in the second one the error is the same as before - ```No route matches```

Comment: No route matches seems like a routing error have you tried calling your endpoint from postman ? you can also check your routes by rake routes.. 
other options would be to add a byebug inside your rspec test and ensure that the id is getting passed correctly or maybe hardcode the id value just to see that the request is reaching the controller action or not..

Comment: Routes are fine because it deletes stock in the production. That's odd.. now I've got other error than before for second solution: ```Failure/Error: let(:user_stock) { UserStock.create(user: user.id, stock: stock) }
     
     ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       User(#70305910165640) expected, got 10 which is an instance of Integer(#70305880349860)```

Comment: Change `UserStock.create(user: user.id, stock: stock)` to `UserStock.create(user_id: user.id, stock: stock)`. You also need to save user first so that it can have an id `User.new(email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password').save`

Comment: Thanks @Thanh but unfortunately it didn't helped - ```Failure/Error: sign_in(user)
     
     RuntimeError:Could not find a valid mapping for true```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm working with `Rails 5.2.3` and my solution was the following:

```
delete "/user_stocks/#{user_stock.id}"
```

However as in some comments on this thread I expirienced a `No route matches` error, my solution was simple, just save the `user_stock` object before the `delete` call. In my case I was testing with an object declared as `UserStock.new` so it didn't has an id, that's why the `delete` call was launching an `No route matches` since it was accessig this path `/user_stocks/` instead of `user_stocks/:id`

Hope this work!